# Filter based on keyword python

Tags: python

I am trying to get only the host information from the below sample data. but somehow i struck. can you pls help

```
DATA="""
TNS Ping Utility for Linux: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on 20-SEP-2023 12:13:43

Copyright (c) 1997, 2022, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
/oracle/rdbms/19.2/network/admin/sqlnet.ora


Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (SDU=32767)(SEND_BUF_SIZE=16777216)(RECV_BUF_SIZE=16777216) (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCPS)(HOST = host1-1-ia2-vip.world.net)(PORT = 1523)) (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCPS)(HOST = host2-2-ia2-vip.world.net)(PORT = 1523)) (LOAD_BALANCE = YES) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = TESTDB92)))
OK (50 msec)
"""

m = re.search('HOST\s\w+\s(\w+)',data) ==> this is not filtering
m.group(1)
```

Desired output :

```
host1-1-ia2-vip.world.net
host1-2-ia2-vip.world.net
```

Comment: This regex is plainly incorrect. You can check out various expressions (with an example working one I provided) at https://regex101.com/r/LBKx8L/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

DATA = "Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (SDU=32767)(SEND_BUF_SIZE=16777216)(RECV_BUF_SIZE=16777216) (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCPS)(HOST =host1-1-ia2-vip.world.net)(PORT = 1523)) (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCPS)(HOST = host2-2-ia2-vip.world.net)(PORT = 1523)) (LOAD_BALANCE = YES) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = TESTDB92)))"

hostnames = re.findall(r'HOST\s*=\s*([\w\.-]+)', DATA)
result = '\n'.join(hostnames)

print(result)
```